# Get current time from server for questionnaire project

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ntp

I am on the last part of multiple choice questionnaire project. I need a common timer for all the candidates appearing in the exam.

Using javascript, timers are working fine but we see the risk that a user could change the system date time to cheat us. So, we need the server date-time to run the countdown timer.

This is our current code:

```
<script>
    var end = new Date("12/3/2016 03:56 PM");
    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;
    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            window.location ="scorecard.php";
            exit;
            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = hours + ": ";
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML += minutes + ": ";
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML += seconds + "";
    }
    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Two variables are used: **end** and **now**.

What I need is the values of these two variables should come from server wherein the **end** should come from a database column which contains the date and time of exam end as : 6/12/2016 3:0 PM and value of **now** should be the current date time of server.

Idea: Since the script will be executed on every page load, even if the user changed his system date-time, my variable will get synchronized on every page reload.